# What is the expected length of the sum of vectors in a multi-dimensional sphere?

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose we pick $m$ vectors i.i.d from the surface of a $d$-dimensional unit sphere (they all have length 1). 
What would be the expected length of their sum?

Equivalently, we can ask about the expected length of their average.

I managed to solve it for 2 vectors in 2 dimensions, but I need a generic solution...

If there's any "known solution" for this problem, even a link will be good enough.

Comment: Hint: use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Do you need an exact answer, or just an approximation? If $d$ is large then you could try approximating the vectors by rescaled Gaussian vectors; the sum of the vectors will itself be a Gaussian vector, and the length will be the square root of a rescaled chi-squared r.v.

Comment: I need an exact answer

Comment: @Igor I'm not seeing how to use your hint. Have you actually thought through a complete solution? I see that this gives me an easy way to compute E(length^2), but this doesn't tell me what E(length) is.

Comment: If I had a formaula, I could probably proove it with induction..

Comment: @David: you are right, it was $E(l^2)$ I computed. The dangers of doing things in your head...

Comment: related question:
http://www.mathhelpforum.com/math-help/f8/distance-random-walk-origin-98875.html

Comment: This isn't very closely related, but I can't resist mentioning the amazing fact that the probability that this length is $<1$ in 2 dimensions is $1/(m+1)$. This might mean there's some hope of a not-too-ugly formula in 2 dimensions.

Comment: I believe I've heard Jon Borwein speak on this topic recently. Have a look at his website, or send him email. 

Answer (score 3):

OK, to atone for my rash comment, I recalled that I needed something related in:

@article {MR2356429,
    AUTHOR = {Rivin, Igor},
     TITLE = {Surface area and other measures of ellipsoids},
   JOURNAL = {Adv. in Appl. Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Advances in Applied Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {39},
      YEAR = {2007},
    NUMBER = {4},
     PAGES = {409--427},
      ISSN = {0196-8858},
   MRCLASS = {52A38 (28A75 33C65 60F99)},
  MRNUMBER = {2356429 (2008k:52012)},
       DOI = {10.1016/j.aam.2006.08.009},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2006.08.009},
}

(see page 414). And found it in the book by Mathai and Provost:

@book {MR1192786,
    AUTHOR = {Mathai, A. M. and Provost, Serge B.},
     TITLE = {Quadratic forms in random variables},
    SERIES = {Statistics: Textbooks and Monographs},
    VOLUME = {126},
      NOTE = {Theory and applications},
 PUBLISHER = {Marcel Dekker Inc.},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1992},
     PAGES = {xxii+367},
      ISBN = {0-8247-8691-2},
   MRCLASS = {62H10 (62E15)},
  MRNUMBER = {1192786 (94g:62110)},
MRREVIEWER = {Donald R. Jensen},
}

It should be in the vicinity of page 62. The argument uses Laplace transforms, and is not trivial.

Comment: Any chance you want to provide a brief explanation for why your comment was rash? It of course seemed reasonable to someone as naive as me.

Comment: As @David Speyer pointed out, I was computing the expectation of the SQUARE of the length (which equals $m$, btw), but this does not tell you what the expectation of the length is...


Answer (score 1):

At http://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/~jb616/walks2.pdf Jonathan Borwein and co-authors discuss $$\int_{[0,1]^n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^ne^{2\pi ix_k}\right|^s\thinspace dx$$ which you may find has some relevance to your question. That paper also has references to others where such integrals are discussed, and there's another paper on Jonathan's website on a closely related topic.